# Use custom JsonSerializerSettings with DocumentDb in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to create a document using the DocumentDb API using custom JsonSerializerSettings. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

I have tried setting

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => {
    return new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver()
        };
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom serialisation of C# poco's for DocumentDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864043/custom-serialisation-of-c-sharp-pocos-for-documentdb)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489768/how-to-tell-documentdb-sdk-to-use-camelcase-during-linq-query

Answer (score 5):

The latest [DocumentDB SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) (1.15.0) exposes now the JsonSerializerSettings.

You can define your custom settings when you create the `DocumentClient` instance:

```
DocumentClient yourClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri("Your Service Endpoint"), "Your Account Key", serializerSettings: new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                // Custom settings
            });
```

Comment: Though you might run into this problem: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/107